# Chrome won't inspect anymore

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, webview, google-chrome-devtools

I need to inspect a Webview running on my tablet which is connected via USB. It used to work but now I get this blank page:

[image]

Instead of the usual developer tools. What's causing the problem? It happened out of the blue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the settings were corrupted. I deleted the history data and now it works again